# Vim syntax highlighting of a Python formatted string

Tags: python, vim, syntax

I am using Vim 8.1 on Debian 11 Bullseye, but it does not work in the recent Vim 8.2 either.

I would like to syntax highlight a Python formatted string, which looks currently in vim so:

[image: is]

but should look like this:

[image: should]

(compare the curly braces and their content)

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this "properly", or can provide the syntax I need to insert in /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/python.vim to achieve this highlighting?

Comment: How about trying `:syntax region pythonFString matchgroup=pythonString start="f'" end="'" skip="\\'" contains=ALL`? It might need tweaks though.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work and I do not have the expertise to apply any 'tweaks'. It colors everything within the formatted string, also the string parts outside the {} pairs (not a problem, but one had to construct four variants of your syntax, because a Python formatted string can be enclosed in (1) single quotes, (2) double quotes, (3) triple single quotes, and (4) triple double quotes). The example image in the OP is colored by the pip/pyperclip package, which does everything right. Also, I have seen several web highlighters doing it right, like stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an appropriate highlighter on github:
https://github.com/vim-python/python-syntax

In .vimrc, you need to enable either everything with

```
let g:python_highlight_all = 1
```

or specifics, like I did:

```
let g:python_highlight_string_format = 1
let g:python_highlight_builtin_objs  = 1
```

A python formatted string now looks like:

[image]

(with my color definitions)